# Python - List index out of range

Tags: python, list

I have been stuck with this question on finding out the second largest number in a list to be read from the console with:

n = size of the list(number of elements) AND 
arr = The list itself

One of the constraints is -100<=A[i]<=100 which I am unable to integrate within my code as I am getting a LIST INDEX OUT OF RANGE ERROR. For instance, this code fails for the custom input: 
3
-10 0 10

but passes for 
3
10 0 10

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())

sortedlist = sorted(arr)
temp = len(sortedlist)

emptylist = []

i = 0 
for temp in range(2, 11):
    if sortedlist[i]<sortedlist[i+1]:
        i+=1
        emptylist.insert(i, sortedlist[i-1])
b = max(emptylist)
print(emptylist)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "solution.py", line 12, in
>    if sortedlist[i]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: So you sort the list then check `if sortedlist[i] < sortedlist[i+1]`, why don't you trust Python builtins to make their job ? And what is `for temp in range(2, 11):` supposed to accomplish ?

Comment: Because `i` is getting incremented every time and you have no checking whether it crossed the list length limit or not

Comment: @polku because it could be `==`

Comment: As for the second case it passes as second element is greater than the third, `i` is not incremented again. So `i` always stays 1

Comment: Got it! I was unnecessarily putting a constraint on temp between 2 and 11 as the question asked but that wasn't needed. For i in range(0, temp-1) did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if sortedlist[i] < sortedlist[i+1]:

The problem lies here. In your example `n = 3` so i can only be 0, 1 or 2. But in your code, `i+1` goes 1, 2 and 3 in the above line, which is out of the array bounds.

You can print `i` and see that `i` goes till 2 which is `n-1` and so `i+1` will be out of bounds. That is one easy way you could debug.

You have to ensure a condition where you do not compare with the next element for the last element.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Issue was with my constraints for i in the for loop. For i in range(0, temp-1) did the job.

Comment: Great! But just out of curiosity, why are you not using `sortedList[-2]` to get the second largest element? Would make your job much easier!

Comment: I guess I got too obsessed with trying to find the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `sortedlist[-2]` to get the second largest number.

In case of repeated numbers you have to use [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) method call over original/sorted list.

`sortedlist = sorted(list(set(arr)))`

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet 
    
        `number_of_inputs = 4  # this is user defined
        i = 0
        collections = list()
        while True:
            user_input = input("Enter your numbers \n")
            if 100 >= user_input >= -100:
                i += 1
                collections.append(user_input)
                if i == number_of_inputs:
                    print "second largest number is \t ",sorted(collections)[-2]
                    break
            else:
                print"this Entry not allowed !!!"`